# What is a third generation web service engine?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

According to Axis 2 documentation in the link https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/contents.html, Apache Axis2, the third generation Web services engine is more efficient, more modular and more XML-oriented than its predecessor Apache Axis.

What does a third generation Web service mean? Can someone explain the evolution of web services and what the different generations refer to?

Comment: It's just a poorly-written sentence. They mean that the latest Axis2 is the third generation of it. Adding the comma missing after "engine" helps make that more clear: *"Apache Axis2, the third generation Web services engine, is more efficient, more modular and more XML-oriented than its predecessor Apache Axis."*

Comment: Even if you add a comma, the phrase 'the third generation Web services engine' seems to be talking in a generic sense than making it seem that Axis2 is the third generation engine of its kind.

Comment: As I said, it's a poorly-written sentence. I'm certain that they just mean it's the third generation of their tool, not that it's a general term they're applying to their tool. *(not my dv)*